# Recommendations on where to get a basic understanding of how to build BI and Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence

The current company I work for has been without a Crystal Reports and BI report developer for over a year now and I have been asked to be trained in the two subjects. I am looking for anywhere I can get a basic understanding of what I am getting in to before the training. I believe the training will mainly focus on developing reports along with just having a small understand with what happens on the back end. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Some handy formulas and overall view[Ken Hamady](https://www.kenhamady.com/formulas/default.html)

[Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sap-crystal-reports-fundamentals) guide is pretty good. ( paid but check microsoft dev essentials)

General tips: save often, backup, supress sections or fields on condition, use the lines on both rulers to help with formating. Also  keep in mind the requriments for the specific report, where information can grow in the future, test diferent scenarios.